# ValueError: c of shape (636,) not acceptable as a color sequence for x with size 636, y with size 636

Tags: pandas, matplotlib

```
plt.figure(figsize=(10,15))
plt.scatter(Matches['id'],Matches['toss_winner'],Matches['id'],Matches['winner'])
```

The above error message is being shown when I run this code.
Matches is a dataframe with 636 rows where 'id' is integer datatype and 'toss_winner' and 'winner' are string datatype

[image: Picture of dataframe head()]

Comment: What is your plot even supposed to show? You say `toss_winner` and `winner` are of type `str`. What does it mean to plot a string?

Comment: I want to know the correlation between 'toss_winner' and 'winner' using scatterplot

Comment: But `toss_winner` and `winner` both contain *strings*. What does the correlation between strings mean to you?

Comment: Are you maybe asking for the respective frequency distributions?

Comment: I want to find out if the team which wins the toss also has a greater chance of winning the match. id is different for different matches

Comment: I'm sorry, but there is a whole lot of logic that is missing here, that you would need to come up with first before you can plot anything. I suggest you start by thinking about what *exactly* the parameters are that you wish to plot. Next, you have to come up with a way of how to extract that information from the data set. Only then can you think about how to plot the data.

Comment: By looking at the overlapping of winners and toss winners point on the scatter plot I can find out they overlap to some extent. I think it would be useful to prove my hypothesis